# Sync data between Angular 2 components go nuts

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I am trying to sync data between two angular components. However it functions a little bit unpredictably.

I have parent component which provides data (synchronously):

```
@Component({
  /*...*/
  directives: [TbInfiniteScrollComponent],
  viewBindings: [TbInfiniteScrollComponent],
  providers: [TbService],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class TbNiV3AppComponent {
  public dealerList:Array<Object> = []

  constructor(service: TbService, private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {

    this.dealerList = service.data.flatten(service.data.get());

  }

  syncData(data){

    /* Unfortunately this doesn't work */

    console.log('syncData!', this.dealerList);
    this.dealerList = [].concat(data);
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }
}
```

And its HTML

```
 <tb-infinite-scroll [tbScrollData]="dealerList" *ngIf="dealerList" (tbDataSync)="syncData($event)" [tbIndent]="true">
   Loading Tree Component...
 </tb-infinite-scroll>
 <tb-infinite-scroll [tbScrollData]="dealerList" *ngIf="dealerList"  (tbDataSync)="syncData($event)">
   Loading Tree Component...
 </tb-infinite-scroll>
```

Then I have child component

```
@Component({
  /* ... */
  selector: 'tb-infinite-scroll',
  inputs: ['rows:tbScrollData', 'tbElHeight:elementHeight', 'tbIndent'],
  outputs: ['tbDataSync'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [TbInfiniteScrollService, ChangeDetectorRef],
})

export class TbInfiniteScrollComponent {

  public tbDataSync:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter()

  private rows:Array<Object> = []

  /* ... */

  assignRows() {
     this.visibleRows = this.service.assignVisible(this.rows, this.elementHeight, this.scroll);
  }

  constructor(private service:TbInfiniteScrollService, private elementRef:ElementRef, private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }   

  toggleVisible(children) {
    this.service.changeVisibility(children);
    this.assignRows();
    this.tbDataSync.emit(this.rows);
  }

}
```

And row HTML

```
 <div class="tb-infinite-scroll__row"
       *ngFor="let row of visibleRows"
       [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': (tbIndent ? (row.level - 1) * 15 : 0) + 'px'}"
       (click)="row.children && toggleVisible(row.children)">
    {{row.name}}
  </div>
```

What it does: it changes the `visible` property of data object children after click and will render only elements with `visible === true`. As both components share the same data set via parent controller I would expect them to render the same output. But after I click a row in one component of which I want to update, the second component should update as well, however it happens kind of randomly.

I believe this gif will explain my problem better.

[image]

How do I force a component to refresh from parent component when bound data changes?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: data object are linked by reference